# How to fill a result set due to missing rows in it, in SQl Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following result set through a stored procedure:

#### Probable Result Set

`Sector || Total || Velocidad || Angulo
2           2       2.29        31.67
3           29      2.35        57.29
4           246     2.63        80.22
6           628     2.87        120.53
7           148     2.62        138.85
8           23      1.93        160.99
9           1       1.38        197.26
13          18      2.62        279.85`.

What I need (due to a requirement) is to fill in the result set according to 'Sector' missing column to 16 rows. Something like this:

#### Expected Result Set

`Sector || Total || Velocidad || Angulo
1           0       null        null
2           2       2.29        31.67
3           29      2.35        57.29
4           246     2.63        80.22
5           0       null        null
6           628     2.87        120.53
7           148     2.62        138.85
8           23      1.93        160.99
9           1       1.38        197.26
10          0       null        null
11          0       null        null
12          0       null        null
13          18      2.62        279.85
14          0       null        null
15          0       null        null
16          0       null        null`.

What do I need  in my stored procedure to implement it before returning result set? Thank you in advance.

**NOTE**: The "Probable Result Set" could vary depending parameters in my stored procedure.

Comment: Take a look at your post and add the missing data.

Comment: Hi Rick, I just edited my post, but could not create the table so i pasted the links.

Comment: Write one query with a series of unions cross joining `select 0 union select 1` with itself until you get a high enough power of 2.  Once you have that query.  Simply left join your query after it and you'll get the result you want.  (oops did I hit delete?  You'll thank me when you learn more SQL doing this yourself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temp Table Inside your Proc**

```
DECLARE @FillerTable 
TABLE(sector INT,total_por_sector INT
          , velocidad_media DECIMAL(10,2), angulo_medio DECIMAL(10,2))
INSERT INTO @FillerTable VALUES
 (1, 0, null, null) ,(2, 0, null, null) ,(3, 0, null, null)
,(4, 0, null, null) ,(5, 0, null, null) ,(6, 0, null, null)
,(7, 0, null, null) ,(8, 0, null, null) ,(9, 0, null, null)
,(10, 0, null, null),(11, 0, null, null),(12, 0, null, null)
,(13, 0, null, null),(14, 0, null, null),(15, 0, null, null);
```

**Insert Missing Data**

```
INSERT INTO YourResultSet  --<-- Your Result Set
SELECT sector, total_por_sector, velocidad_media, angulo_medio
FROM @FillerTable ft
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM YourResultSet
                  WHERE sector = ft.sector)
```